# Java Genuine Windows Dialogs

Tags: java, windows

I am making a Java application, until I realized that Java doesn't use the Genuine Windows dialog layout.

I used this to set the UI layout to the system default (in this case, Windows):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

I realized that dialogs created using this look and feel is different from Windows default.

Compare these two dialogs (first is Windows, second is Java):

[image: Windows]
[image: java]

Am I wrong, or is there a way?

Comment: Of course there's a way: use something other than Java (accessed from Java via JNI, if you're feeling masochistic).

Comment: Nope, this correct behaviour, there are always going to be slight differences between the "official" OS and what Java's look and feels can replicated. If it's really Important to you, you could consider creating your own

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like OP is on SO anymore, but regardless, if your goal is to create an application with the same look and feel as native applications, you might consider using [Eclipse SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/).

To achieve nearly the same look and feel as the top image, you can use the SWT [MessageBox](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FMessageBox.html).

For example:

```
final MessageBox box = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.YES | SWT.NO | SWT.ICON_WARNING);
box.setText("Rename");
box.setMessage("If you change a file name extension, the file might become unusable.\n\nAre you sure you want to change it?");
box.open();
```

will create:

[image]

I'm not aware of a way to remove the X cancel button, but there may be a way.